# Display nested arrays in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm pretty new to vue and can get my way around this.

I'm receiving some JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "jack",
    "age": "twenty",
    "Colors": {
      "favorite": "blue",
      "hate": "orange",
      "surprise": "violet"
    },
   
    "Food": {
     "favorite": "barbecue",
      "hate": "broccoli",
      "surprise": "pasta"
      "new": [
        "pizza",
        "ice cream"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I'm trying to get this:

**Name**: Jack

**Age**: Twenty

**Colors**

- **Favorite**: Blue
- **Hate**: Orange
- **Surprise**: Violet

**Food**

- **Favorite**: Barbecue
- **Hate**: Broccoli
- **Surprise**: Pasta
- **New**:

  - Pizza
  - Ice cream

HTML

```
<p><strong>Name:</strong> Jack</p>
<p><strong>Age:</strong> Twenty</p>
<p><strong>Colors</strong>
   <ul>
      <li><strong>Favorite:<strong> Blue</li>
      <li><strong>Hate:<strong> Orange</li>
      <li><strong>Surprise:<strong> Violet</li>
   </ul>
</p>
<p><strong>Food</strong>
   <ul>
      <li><strong>Favorite:<strong> Barbecue</li>
      <li><strong>Hate:<strong> Broccoli</li>
      <li><strong>Surprise:<strong> Pasta</li>
      <li><strong>New:<strong>
         <ul>
            <li>Pizza</li>
            <li>Ice cream</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</p>
```

So I did this:

HTML

```
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
       <div>
          <p><strong>{{title}}</strong> {{item}}</p>
          <p v-for="(category, index) in item" :key="index"><strong>{{index}}</strong> {{category}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```
import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        name: 'theComponent',
        props: {},
        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            const url = 'https://api-json-url'
            axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    this.items= response.data[0]
                })
        }
    };
```

But I'm getting this:

**Name**: Jack

**0**:J

**1**:a

**2**:c

**3**:k

**Age**: Twenty

**0**:T

**1**:w

**2**:e

**3**:n

**1**:t

**2**:y

**Colors**: {"favorite": "blue","hate": "orange","surprise": "violet"}

- **Favorite**: Blue
- **Hate**: Orange
- **Surprise**: Violet

**Food** {"favorite": "barbecue","hate": "broccoli","surprise": "pasta","new":["pizza","ice cream"]}

- **Favorite**: Barbecue
- **Hate**: Broccoli
- **Surprise**: Pasta
- **New**:["pizza","ice cream"]

HTML

```
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> Jack</p>
    <p><strong>0</strong>J</p>
    <p><strong>1</strong>a</p>
    <p><strong>2</strong>c</p>
    <p><strong>3</strong>k</p>
    <p><strong>Age:</strong> Twenty</p>
    <p><strong>0</strong>T</p>
    <p><strong>1</strong>w</p>
    <p><strong>2</strong>e</p>
    <p><strong>3</strong>n</p>
    <p><strong>1</strong>t</p>
    <p><strong>2</strong>y</p>
    <p><strong>Colors</strong> {"favorite": "blue","hate": "orange","surprise": "violet"}</p>
    <p>
       <ul>
          <li><strong>Favorite:<strong> Blue</li>
          <li><strong>Hate:<strong> Orange</li>
          <li><strong>Surprise:<strong> Violet</li>
       </ul>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Food</strong> {"favorite": "barbecue","hate": "broccoli","surprise": "pasta","new":["pizza","ice cream"]}</p>
    <p>
       <ul>
          <li><strong>Favorite:<strong> Barbecue</li>
          <li><strong>Hate:<strong> Broccoli</li>
          <li><strong>Surprise:<strong> Pasta</li>
          <li><strong>New:<strong>["pizza","ice cream"]</li>
       </ul>
    </p>
```

I think that I need something like isArray() with some v-if just before the first v-for. But I can't get there. I've tried with length also, but no.

Comment: You need to access `item.name`, `item.category`, etc. in the template directly. If you don't know the key names, you need to use e.g. `Object.keys` to get the keys to iterate through. Do you want to recursively go through each element? Then, you need to check if the value is an object, an array or a primitive value/string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive done a rough version based on your example on jsFiddle: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kxhgr127/1/)

So basically you need to loop through the items and check if the value is array or object then you'll have to loop through them again like:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in Object.entries(items[0])" :key="index">
    <div v-if="typeof item[1] !='object'">
      <p>
        <strong>{{item[0]}}:</strong> {{item[1]}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <p>
        <strong>{{item[0]}}:</strong>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(innerItem, innerIndex) in  Object.entries(item[1]) ">
            <div v-if="!Array.isArray(innerItem[1])">
              <p>


                <strong>{{innerItem[0]}}:</strong>
                <span>{{innerItem[1]}}</span>
              </p>


            </div>
            <div v-else>
              <strong>{{innerItem[0]}}:</strong>

              <ul>
                <li v-for="(it2,in2) in innerItem[1]">{{it2}}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```